# Constructing mysql tablenames in query

Tags: php, mysql

This is properly going to be really obvious but been driving me insane for far to long.

I have a bunch of tables in a MySql database, example of these are

//Table Names 000001_table1, 000001_table2, 000002_table1, 000002_table2, 000003_table1, 000003_tabel2

In php i can programmatically create these tables

```
$db->query("CREATE TABLE {$tablenum}_table1 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, COL1 TEXT, COL2 TEXT, COL3 TEXT)")
```

However when i come to read these tables I'm getting issues

Using the following query

```
$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from {$tablenum}_table1")
```

I get the error

```
Table 'database.000001' doesn't exist[]
```

If i put backspaces around it, i get the error

Can't find file: '.\database\000001@000d@000a_table1.frm' (errno: 22 - Invalid argument)[]

If i try constructing the table name before the query i get the same issue.

Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks around your tablename:

```
$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from `" . $tablenum . "_table1`")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried that but i get the error       Can't find file: '.\database\000001@000d@000a_table1.frm' (errno: 22 - Invalid argument)[]

Comment: with the update answer I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

looks like your {$tablenum}_table1 converts it to
{$tablenum}._table1
(an extra dot is inserted and he thinks it is **00001.table1** which means: 
table1 FROM database 00001

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the variable tablename like this:

```
$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from ${tablenum}_table1")
```